# CronJob not running

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I have set up a cronjob for root user in ubuntu environment as follows by typing `crontab -e`

```
  34 11 * * * sh /srv/www/live/CronJobs/daily.sh
  0 08 * * 2 sh /srv/www/live/CronJobs/weekly.sh
  0 08 1 * * sh /srv/www/live/CronJobs/monthly.sh
```

But the cronjob does not run. I have tried checking if the cronjob is running using `pgrep cron` and that gives process id 3033. The shell script calls a python file and is used to send an email. Running the python file is ok. There's no error in it but the cron doesn't run. The daily.sh file has the following code in it.

```
python /srv/www/live/CronJobs/daily.py
python /srv/www/live/CronJobs/notification_email.py
python /srv/www/live/CronJobs/log_kpi.py
```

Comment: Bear in mind that cron jobs do not run with all the environment that an interactive command would - for instance, when you call "python",  that's being looked up to a full file path based on the environment variable $PATH. You should specify the path in full to avoid that dependency.

Comment: Another class of crontab problem not covered here are `PATH`/environment related problems, which are covered in [Running a bash script from a cronjob fails with “No such file or directory”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45743633/850848).

Comment: A common problem with `cron` in Docker is that many Docker images out of the box do not run `cron` at all, and setting it up can be quite a hassle. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container

Comment: Another common beginner error is "where do I write this `* * * * *` stuff?" See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595705/command-not-found-cron

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Following is the solution:-

1. Never use relative path in python scripts to be executed via crontab.
   I did something like this instead:-

   ```
   import os
   import sys
   import time, datetime

   CLASS_PATH = '/srv/www/live/mainapp/classes'
   SETTINGS_PATH = '/srv/www/live/foodtrade'
   sys.path.insert(0, CLASS_PATH)
   sys.path.insert(1,SETTINGS_PATH)

   import other_py_files
   ```
2. Never supress the crontab code instead use mailserver and check the mail for the user. That gives clearer insights of what is going.

Comment: Also never forget the hashbangs    #!/usr/bin/env python at the top :-)

Comment: Relative paths are fine if you know what you are doing. `cron` jobs will be started in the home directory of the user whose job is executing.

Comment: If your system is not configured to send email, any `cron` output will be lost. If you can't - or don't want to - configure mail on the box just for troubleshooting, probably make sure you write _everything_ to a log file (i.e. `* * * * * whatever >>filename 2>&1` where you have write access to `filename` and understand that you probably want to specify a full path to the directory where the file should be written, though if you don't, you are referring to your home directory).

Comment: Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Answer (score 364):

#### WTF?! My cronjob doesn't run?!

Here's a checklist guide to debug not running cronjobs:

1. Is the Cron daemon running?

- Run `ps ax | grep cron` and look for cron.
- Debian: `service cron start` or `service cron restart`

2. Is cron working?

- `* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/file`
- Syntax correct? See below.
- You obviously need to have write access to the file you are redirecting the output to. A unique file name in `/tmp` which does not currently exist should always be writable.
- Probably also add `2>&1` to include standard error as well as standard output, or separately output standard error to another file with `2>>/tmp/errors`

3. Is the command working standalone?

- Check if the script has an error, by doing a dry run on the CLI
- When testing your command, test as the user whose crontab you are editing, which might not be your login or root

4. Can cron run your job?

- Check `/var/log/cron.log` or `/var/log/messages` for errors.
- Ubuntu: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`
- Redhat: `/var/log/cron`

5. Check permissions

- Set executable flag on the command: `chmod +x /var/www/app/cron/do-stuff.php`
- If you redirect the output of your command to a file, verify you have permission to write to that file/directory

6. Check paths

- Check she-bangs / hashbangs line
- Do not rely on environment variables like `PATH`, as their value will likely not be the same under cron as under an interactive session. See [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)

7. Don't suppress output while debugging

- Commonly used is this suppression: `30 1 * * * command > /dev/null 2>&1`
- Re-enable the standard output or standard error message output by removing `>/dev/null 2>&1` altogether; or perhaps redirect to a file in a location where you have write access: `>>cron.out 2>&1` will append standard output and standard error to `cron.out` in the invoking user's home directory.
- If you don't redirect output from a `cron` job, the daemon will try to send you any output or error messages by email. Check your inbox (maybe simply `more $MAIL` if you don't have a mail client). If mail is not available, maybe check for a file named `dead.letter` in your home directory, or system log entries saying that the output was discarded. Especially in the latter case, probably edit the job to add redirection to a file, then wait for the job to run, and examine the log file for error messages or other useful feedback.
- If you are trying to figure out why something failed, the error messages will be visible in this file. Read it and understand it.

#### Still not working? Yikes!

1. Raise the cron debug level

- Debian

  - in `/etc/default/cron`
  - set `EXTRA_OPTS="-L 2"`
  - `service cron restart`
  - `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to see the scripts executed
- Ubuntu

  - in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`
  - add or comment out line `cron.* /var/log/cron.log`
  - reload logger `sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`
  - re-run cron
  - open `/var/log/cron.log`  and look for detailed error output
- Reminder: deactivate log level, when you are done with debugging

2. Run cron and check log files again

#### Cronjob Syntax

```
# Minute  Hour  Day of Month      Month         Day of Week    User Command    
# (0-59) (0-23)   (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec) (0-6 or Sun-Sat)  
         
    0       2       *             *                *          root /usr/bin/find
```

This syntax is **only** correct for the `root` user. Regular user `crontab` syntax doesn't have the *User* field (regular users aren't allowed to run code as any other user);

```
# Minute  Hour  Day of Month      Month         Day of Week    Command    
# (0-59) (0-23)   (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec) (0-6 or Sun-Sat)  
         
    0       2       *             *                *          /usr/bin/find
```

#### Crontab Commands

1. `crontab -l`

   - Lists all the user's cron tasks.
2. `crontab -e`, for a specific user: `crontab -e -u agentsmith`

   - Starts edit session of your crontab file.
   - When you exit the editor, the modified crontab is installed automatically.
3. `crontab -r`

   - Removes your crontab entry from the cron spooler, but not from crontab file.

Comment: A couple of extra points that should probably be included here: 1) when testing your command, test as the user whose crontab you are editing, which might not be your login or root; 2) as I mentioned above, it's best not to rely on environment variables like `PATH` at all, as their value will likely not be the same under cron as under an interactive session.

Comment: Another thing for the checklist: make sure whatever you are trying to execute is not in an encrypted (home) folder.

Comment: Linux uses an extended `crontab` syntax which supports time expressions like `*/5` or `3,11,19`. If you are trying to use expressions like this and you are not on full-scale Linux/Vixie `cron`, check the local manual page whether these are supported.

Comment: Also, make sure that the user for the cron job does not have an expired password.

Comment: ... or maybe you didn't install the cron package : sudo yum install cron

Comment: Add another reason... the system clock is off

Comment: `/bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/file` might be too crude and uninformative; try `date +'\%c: cron works' >>/tmp/file` to see when exactly it ran.

Comment: Also check timezone. If you change timezone of the system since crond starts, you need to restart the daemon.

Comment: In my case, user was homeless and first thing cron did was to try to cd to /home/$USER which failed.  Only clue was in /var/log/cron.log
Solution.  `HOME=/tmp` at top of crontab

Comment: For me adding "2>>/tmp/errors" to end of cron job command help identify that while in cron, the job did not find php. No other clue in cron.log or messages.

Comment: To add one more debugging possibility here since I just went through this: 

Asterisks (*) are not the same as 0s. 

I was banging my head against the wall wondering why my very basic test script wouldn't run only to realize that it wasn't set for the right day, month, etc because I used 0s instead of *s

Comment: WARNING: On my system (Ubuntu 20.04), the day-of-week ("dow") starts on MONDAY, not SUNDAY. Wow! Lost me an hour checking everything else. Heads up!!

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, I think your timezone is wrong in this case.

Comment: Timezone was my problem. I set the job to a time that I expect but the server was running in UTC.

Comment: Seams that nobody remembered to mention that cron uses the "run-parts" module to run the scripts in the /etc/cron.???/ folders. You can use the "run-parts" options: --test, --list, or --verbose to help debug what's going on.

Comment: "run-parts" is a good suggestion (referencing: https://superuser.com/a/402782/441096). The command itself and some of its CLI options might not be available on all Linux distros, but on Debian it should be fine.

Answer (score 37):

Another reason crontab will fail: Special handling of the `%` character.

From the [manual file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html):

```
The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a
"%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified
in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.  A "%" character in the
command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be changed into
newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to
the command as standard input.
```

In my particular case, I was using `date --date="7 days ago" "+%Y-%m-%d"` to produce parameters to my script, and it was failing silently.  I finally found out what was going on when I checked `syslog` and saw my command was truncated at the `%` symbol.  You need to escape it like this:

```
date --date="7 days ago" "+\%Y-\%m-\%d"
```

See here for more details:

http://www.ducea.com/2008/11/12/using-the-character-in-crontab-entries/

Comment: This is precisely the issue I was having: `sh /path/script.sh /path/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt` needed to be: `sh /path/script.sh /path/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).txt`

Answer (score 11):

I want to add 2 points that I learned:

1. Cron config files put in /etc/cron.d/ should not contain a dot (.). Otherwise, it won't be read by cron.
2. If the user running your command is not in /etc/shadow. It won't be allowed to schedule cron.

**Refs:**

1. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/cron.8.html
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: The convention to skip files with dots in their names extends to anything `.d` and is an implementation detail, I think of the Debian `run-parts` script; so this advice is probably specific to Debian-based architectures.

Answer (score 4):

It might also be a timezone problem.

Cron uses the local time.

Run the command `timedatectl` to see the machine time and make sure that your crontab is in this same timezone.

- https://askubuntu.com/a/536489/1043751

Answer (score 4):

To add another point, a file in /etc/cron.d must contain an empty new line at the end. This is likely related to the response by Luciano which specifies that:

```
The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a "%"
character, will be executed
```

Comment: When you experience "some" of your crons running but "not all", especially the last in the cron tab, this can be the reason.

Comment: Generally, all text files shoud have a final newline on Unix-like platforms. Per POSIX, they are not valid text files if they don't.

Answer (score 2):

I found useful debugging information on an Ubuntu 16.04 server by running:

`systemctl status cron.service`

In my case I was kindly informed I had left a comment '#' off of a remark line:

```
Aug 18 19:12:01 is-feb19 cron[14307]: Error: bad minute; while reading /etc/crontab
Aug 18 19:12:01 is-feb19 cron[14307]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to the link below.

[similar to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-executing-a-python-script)
[my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667657/issue-submitting-a-cron-job-using-crontab?noredirect=1#comment119608694_67667657)

#### My Issue

My issue was that cron / crontab wouldn't execute my bash script.  that bash script executed a python script.

#### original bash file

```sh
#!/bin/bash

python /home/frosty/code/test_scripts/test.py
```

#### python file (test.py)

```py
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    dt_now = datetime.now()
    string_now = dt_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    with open('./text_file.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'wrote at {string_now}\n')

    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### the error I was getting

```
  File "/home/frosty/code/test_scripts/test.py", line 7
    string_to_write = f'wrote at {string_now}\n'
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this error didn't make sense because the code executed without error from the bash file and the python file.

** Note -> ensure in the `crontab -e` file you don't suppress the output.  I sent the output to a file by adding `>>/path/to/cron/output/file.log 2>&1` after the command.  below is my crontab -e entry

```sh
*/5 * * * * /home/frosty/code/test_scripts/echo_message_sh >>/home/frosty/code/test_scripts/cron_out.log 2>&1
```

#### the issue

cron was using the wrong python interpreter, probably python 2 from the syntax error.

#### how I solved the problem

I changed my bash file to the following

```sh
#!/bin/bash

conda_shell=/home/frosty/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda_env=base

source ${conda_shell}
conda activate ${conda_env}

python /home/frosty/code/test_scripts/test.py
```

And I changed my python file to the following

```py
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    dt_now = datetime.now()
    string_now = dt_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    string_file = '/home/frosty/code/test_scripts/text_file.txt'
    string_to_write = 'wrote at {}\n'.format(string_now)
    with open(string_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(string_to_write)

    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There are two distinct issues here. If it's just that `python` runs the wrong Python version, the simple fix is to specify the path to the version you want to run, like maybe `/opt/local/python3.10/bin/python` instead of just `python`. A virtual environment has the additional benefit that you can install libraries specific to that environment; the standard solution to that is the `venv` module in the Python 3 standard library, though Conda is a popular third-party alternative with some unique features.

Comment: If you have a standard `venv` environment in `$HOME/myprovect/venv` in which you want to run `$HOME/myproject/script.py`, you don't need to `activate` it separately; you can simply run it with `$HOME/myproject/venv/bin/python $HOME/myproject/script.py`

Comment: Very Beautiful Answer

Answer (score 2):

As this is becoming a canonical for troubleshooting `cron` issues, allow me to add one specific but rather complex issue: If you are attempting to run a GUI (or otherwise interactive) program from `cron`, you are probably *Doing It Wrong.*

A common symptom is receiving error messages about `DISPLAY` being unset, or the `cron` job's process being unable to access the display.

In brief, this means that the program you are trying to run is attempting to render something on an X11 (or Wayland etc) display, and failing, because `cron` is not attached to a graphical environment, or in fact any kind of input/output facility at all, beyond being able to read and write files, and send email if the system is configured to allow that.

For the purposes of "I'm unable to run my interactive `cron` job", let's just point out in broad strokes three common scenarios for this problem.
Probably identify the case you are trying to implement, and search for related questions about that particular scenario to learn more, and find actual solutions with actual code.

1. If you are trying to develop an interactive program which communicates with a user, you want to rethink your approach. A common, but nontrivial, arrangement is to split the program in two: A back-end service which can run from `cron`, but which does not have any user-visible interactive facilities, and a front-end client which the user runs from their GUI when they want to communicate with the back-end service.

   Probably your user client should simply be added to the user(s)' GUI startup script if it needs to be, or they want to, run automatically when they log in.

   I suppose the back-end service could be started from `cron`, but if it requires a GUI to be useful, maybe start it from the X11 server's startup scripts instead; and if not, probably run it from a regular startup script (`systemd` these days, or `/etc/rc.local` or a similar system startup directory more traditionally).<sup>1</sup>
2. If you are trying to run a GUI program without interacting with a real user <sup>2</sup>, you may be able to set up a "headless" X11 server <sup>3</sup> and run a `cron` job which starts up that server, runs your job, and quits.

   Probably your job should simply run a suitable X11 server from `cron` (separate from any interactive X11 server which manages the actual physical display(s)  and attached graphics card(s) and keyboard(s) available to the system), and pass it a configuration which runs the client(s) you want to run once it's up and running. (See also the next point for some practical considerations.)
3. You are running a computer for the sole purpose of displaying a specific application in a GUI, and you want to start that application when the computer is booted.

   Probably your startup scripts should simply run the GUI (X11 or whatever) and hook into its startup script to also run the client program once the GUI is up and running.  In other words, you don't need `cron` here; just configure the startup scripts to run the desktop GUI, and configure the desktop GUI to run your application as part of the (presumably automatic, guest?) login sequence.<sup>4</sup>

There *are* ways to run X11 programs on the system's primary display (`DISPLAY=:0.0`) but doing that from a `cron` job is often problematic, as that display is usually reserved for actual interactive use by the first user who logs in and starts a graphical desktop. On a single-user system, you might be able to live with the side effects if that user is also you, but this tends to have inconvenient consequences and scale very poorly.

An additional complication is deciding which user to run the `cron` job as.  A shared system resource like a back-end service can and probably should be run by `root` (though ideally have a dedicated system account which it switches into once it has acquired access to any privileged resources it needs) but anything involving a GUI should definitely not be run as `root` at any point.

A related, but distinct problem is to interact in any meaningful way with the user. If you can identify the user's active session (to the extent that this is even well-defined in the first place), how do you grab their attention without interfering with whatever else they are in the middle of? But more fundamentally, how do you even find them? If they are not logged in at all, what do you do then? If they are, how do you determine that they are active and available? If they are logged in more than once, which terminal are they using, and is it safe to interrupt that session? Similarly, if they are logged in to the GUI, they might miss a window you spring up on the local console, if they are actually logged in remotely via VNC or a remote X11 server.

As a further aside: On dedicated servers (web hosting services, supercomputing clusters, etc) you might even be breaking the terms of service of the hosting company or institution if you install an interactive graphical desktop you can connect to from the outside world, or even at all.

---

<sup>1</sup>
The `@reboot` hook in `cron` is a convenience for regular users who don't have any other facility for running something when the system comes up, but it's just inconvenient and obscure to hide something there if you are `root` anyway and have complete control over the system. Use the system facilities to launch system services.

<sup>2</sup>
A common use case is running a web browser which needs to run a full GUI client, but which is being controlled programmatically and which doesn't really need to display anything anywhere, for example to scrape sites which use Javascript and thus require a full graphical browser to render the information you want to extract.

Another is poorly designed scientific or office software which was not written for batch use, and thus requires a GUI even when you just want to run a batch job and then immediately quit without any actual need to display anything anywhere.

(In the latter case, probably review the documentation to check if there isn't a `--batch` or `--noninteractive` or `--headless` or `--script` or `--eval` option or similar to run the tool without the GUI, or perhaps a separate utility for noninteractive use.)

<sup>3</sup>
`Xvfb` is the *de facto* standard solution; it runs a "virtual framebuffer" where the computer can spit out pixels as if to a display, but which isn't actually connected to any display hardware.

<sup>4</sup>
There are several options here.
The absolutely simplest is to set up the system to automatically log in a specific user at startup without a password prompt, and configure that user's desktop environment (Gnome or KDE or XFCE or what have you) to run your script from its "Startup Items" or "Login Actions" or "Autostart" or whatever the facility might be called. If you need more control over the environment, maybe run bare X11 without a desktop environment or window manager at all, and just run your script instead. Or in some cases, maybe replace the X11 login manager ("greeter") with something custom built.

The X11 stack is quite modular, and there are several hooks in various layers where you could run a script either as part of a standard startup process, or one which completely replaces a standard layer. These things tend to differ somewhat between distros and implementations, and over time, so this answer is necessarily vague and incomplete around these matters. Again, probably try to find an existing question about how to do things for your specific platform (Ubuntu, Raspbian, Gnome, KDE, what?) and scenario. For simple scenarios, perhaps see [Ubuntu - run bash script on startup with visible terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966767/ubuntu-run-bash-script-on-startup-with-visible-terminal)

Comment: Perhaps see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-the-display-environment-variable/919913#919913

Comment: For autostarting GUI things, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44288/run-gui-application-on-startup#44289

Comment: _This_ is the answer that it took me three days to find. I'm trying to call a yad/zenity script from incrond. I tried all the DISPLAY=:0 and .Xauthority environment combinations that I could find on SE, and now I have to start learning pipes :) I guess I've been putting it off for too long now...

Comment: @Conrado Sounds as such like `DISPLAY=:0.0` should work for that scenario, if you are running it as the user who runs that X11 session and the display is actually `:0.0` but there are many scenarios where either of those could be untrue. Also, pipes sounds like the wrong tangent to go on next, but without knowing more about your problem, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Oh, I thought that option 1 above meant to use pipes to communicate from the back end to the front end. I can make the incron back end job work fine, and if I call my front-end script from a terminal window in xfce, it works just the way I want, but I don't know how to tie the two together. My first attempts at using a pipe haven't been successful either. What did you mean in option 1 if not a pipe?

Comment: @Conrado Pipes can work but sockets are probably the most common solution.

Answer (score 2):

**No MTA installed, discarding output**

I had a similar problem with a PHP file executed as a CRON job.
When I manually execute the file it works, but not with CRON tab.

I got the output message: **"No MTA installed, discarding output"**

Postfix is the default Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) in Ubuntu and can be installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

But this same message can be also output when you add a log file as below and it does not have proper write permission to /path/to/logfile.log

```
/path/to/php -f /path/to/script.php >> /path/to/logfile.log
```

The permission issue can occur if you create the cron-log file manually using a command like `touch` while you are logged in as a different user and you add CRONs in the tab of another user(group) like `www-data` using: `sudo crontab -u www-data -e`. Then CRON daemon tries to write to the log file and fail, then tries to send the output as an email using Ubuntu's MTA and when it's not found, outputs "No MTA installed, discarding output".

To prevent this:

- Create the file with proper permission.
- Avoid creating the relevant CRON log file manually, add the log in CRON tab and let the log file get created automatically when the cron is run.

Comment: Properly installing and configuring an MTA is a broader topic, and not suitable for Stack Overflow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another reason for user's crontab not running: the hostname is not present on the hosts file:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/hostname
ubuntu
```

Now the hosts file:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

This is on a Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, the way to fix it is **adding the hostname to the hosts file** so it resembles something like this:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 ubuntu localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was that the file cron was trying to run was in an encrypted directory, more specifcically a user diretory on /home/. Although the crontab was configured as root, because the script being run exisited in an encrypted user directory in /home/ cron could only read this directory when the user was actually logged in. To see if the directory is encrypted check if this directory exists:

```
/home/.ecryptfs/<yourusername>
```

if so then you have an encrypted home directory.

The fix for me was to move the script in to a non=encrypted directory and everythig worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Copying my answer for [a duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69122457/4420129) here.

cron may not know where to find the Python interpreter because it doesn't share your user account's environment variables.

There are 3 solutions to this:

1. If Python is at `/usr/bin/python`, you can change the cron job to use an absolute path: `/usr/bin/python /srv/www/live/CronJobs/daily.py`
2. Alternatively you can also add a PATH value to the crontab with `PATH=/usr/bin`.
3. Another solution would be to specify an interpreter in the script file, make it executable, and call the script itself in your crontab:

   a. Put shebang at the top of your python file: `#!/usr/bin/python`.

   b. Set it to executable: `$ chmod +x /srv/www/live/CronJobs/daily.py`

   c. Put it in crontab: `/srv/www/live/CronJobs/daily.py`

Adjust the path to the Python interpreter if it's different on your system.

[Reference](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=162994)

Answer (score 1):

**CRON uses a different TIMEZONE**

A very  common issue is: cron time settings may is different than your. In particular, the timezone could be not be the same:

```
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
```

You can run:

```
* * * * * echo $(date) >> /tmp/test.txt
```

This should generate a file like:

```
# cat test.txt 
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:02:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:03:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:04:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:05:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:06:01 AM UTC
```

If you are using a TZ other than UTC, you can try:

```
timedatectl set-timezone America/Sao_Paulo
```

replace `America/Sao_Paulo` according to you settings.

I'm not sure if it is actually necessary, but you can run:

```
sudo systemctl restart cron.service
```

After that, cron works as I expected:

```
# cat test.txt 
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:02:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:03:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:04:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:05:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:06:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:07:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:08:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:09:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 09:10:01 AM UTC
Sun 03 Apr 2022 06:11:01 AM -03
Sun 03 Apr 2022 06:12:01 AM -03
Sun 03 Apr 2022 06:13:01 AM -03
Sun 03 Apr 2022 06:14:01 AM -03
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, my cronjobs were working fine until there was a power shortage that cut the power to my Raspberry Pi and Cron got corrupted. I think it was running a long Python script exactly when the shortage happened.

The solution was to force re-installation of cron with:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install cron
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
service cron start
```

or

```
systemctl start cron
```

In my case I was trying to run cron locally.
I checked status:

```
service cron status
```

It showed me:

```
* cron is not running
```

Then I simply started the service:

```
service cron start
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the command that cron needs to run is in a directory where cron has no access, typically on systems where users' home directories' permissions are 700 and the command is in that directory.

Comment: The user themself will have access to that directory just fine; why would another user, or the system user, want to run their script, from `cron` or otherwise? System scripts should be owned by the system (and then of course accessible to all users if they are the target audience).

Answer (score -1):

I experienced same problem where crons are not running. 
We fixed by changing permissions and owner by
Crons made root owner as we had mentioned in crontab AND
Cronjobs 644 permission given

Comment: 644 is wrong for anything you want to execute. A script file should generally have 755 (or perhaps 775 if you are on an architecture where the group is always unique; though even then 755 should work). Eventually, you need to actually understand what these permissions mean.

Answer (score -1):

Although answer has been accepted for this question, I will like to add what worked for me.
it's a good idea to quote the URL, if it contains a query it may not work without everything being quoted.

DONT FORGET TO PUT YOUR URL WHICH CONTAINS "?, =, #, %" IN A QUOTE.

Example.
https://paystack.com/indexphp?docs/api/#transaction-charge-authorization&date=today
should be in a quote like so
"https://paystack.com/indexphp?docs/api/#transaction-charge-authorization&date=today"

Comment: @tripleee I dont get the essence of your comment and the markdown? the question was clear, my answer was on point but you just wanted to be heard.

Comment: The top-voted answer already explains how to troubleshoot general shell scripting problems. Adding new "answers" about yet another way to wreck your shell script produces noise, not value. If your shell script doesn't run without `cron`, then of course it also will not run with `cron`.

Comment: the top-voted didn't address the issue with quotes around string URL with parameters. At least that was my issue. unless you want to say it doesn't generally address issues why some cron tasks don't run.

Comment: Just like it doesn't address many other common shell programming errors. Did you forget to `chmod` your script? Should that be another answer? Did you use a DOS editor and wreck the line endings? Should that be another answer? None of these are specific to `cron` or touched on at all in the question.