# Allow server to run cron jobs but block access to normal user with .htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cron

have a cron job that is located in a folder in the normal directory.

I am trying to not allow access to this file by anyone else EXCEPT my server for running the cron job.

I tried:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

But no luck. I have gone down the root of putting the cron job outside the web root but i could not get it to run no matter what me and my host tried.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Two things here: (a) getting the cronjob to run, (b) access restriction.

**Cronjob**

New crontab entry:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /somewhere/www/cronjob.php
```

Set correct permissons on cronjob.php:

- Execute flag: `chmod +x /somewhere/www/cronjob.php`

**Access Restriction**

In general, it is a good practice, to place the script files for cronjobs outside of the `www` path.

If you really need to place them in `www`, then you might protect them with an access restriction. For the webserver Apache, this would work via .htaccess, like so:

`.htaccess` inside `/somewhere/www/`:

```
<Files "cronjob.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

This protects the file cronjob.php from outside access, but allows cron to execute the file.

If nothing works, follow my step by step guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744360/1163786

Comment: tested that but it doesnt run. The cronjob works fine without any htaccess restrictions. What do you mean by the first part, how do i set permissions on the cronjob?

Comment: `chmod +x /somewhere/www/cronjob.php`. keep in mind that different users are involved here. please check the user related permissions with `chown` and `chgrp`. the web-user is often "www-data" - that's not the "cron" executing user, right...

Answer (score 0):

You can restricted the access by set the environment in crontab file

> SCRIPT_RUN_ENV=mycronenv

and validte the environment string within the function:

```
if (get_env('SCRIPT_RUN_ENV') != 'mycronenv') {
    die('Access denied');
}
```

OR you can restrict the access by IP

```
if( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "127.0.0.1" ){
    die('Access denied!');
}
```

And you can set the permission to your scripting file through .htaccess like:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from THIS_SERVER_IP
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
```

Comment: I thought at the second solution and came here for better ones, still gonna use that one, it's the easiest one.