# Cron job does not run in RHEL

Tags: cron, rhel

I'm running RHEL and I'm trying to set up a cron job to run a shell script every 5 minutes.

Following the directions here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Automating_System_Tasks.html#s2-configuring-cron-jobs

I have `service crond start` and `chkconfig crond on`. Then I edited /etc/crontab and added:

`*/5 * * * * my-user /path/to/shell.sh`

I did a `chmod +x shell.sh`. And I made sure to add a new line character at the end.

I'm expecting it to run every 5 minutes but it never executes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CronJob not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Comment: How did find out that it doesn't run? There are several definitions of it running. For example: the whole crontab may not be running at all. Or this specific cronjob may not be executed becuase of a syntax error. Or the file doesn't have the correct execution rights. Or the file itself contains errors. So what exactly did you find out so far?

Comment: Ah @Cfx 's post links to an excellent answer indeed

Answer (score 2):

Simply try to add the cronjob entry and check the script is working fine or not by taking the viewable output in the script.

```
echo "test time - $(date)" > script.sh
chmod +x script.sh
crontab -e
```

Then enter the cronjob as below,

```
*/5 * * * * sh /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/log.file
```

Check if the log is writing correctly. If its fine, better cross check the script that you are trying to execute via cron. Otherwise it will be a cron issue.