# My Cron is not running

Tags: linux, bash, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I have a list of cronjob set to run in a regular schedule.
After read and tried this suggestion here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744360/1478789

I still haven't able to figure it out why my cron job is not running.

[image: Result: ps ax | grep cron]

When I tried with this simple command:

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /home/user/somefile.log
```

It does not append any text to the intended file.

So, I try to do it "manually" by executing the following command:

```
user@machine:~$ echo "Random text" >> /home/user/somefile.log
```

It appends some text to the file.

Lastly, when I issue the following command:

```
user@machine:~$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

It doesn't print anything at all

By the way, I edit my cron

```
user@machine:~$ sudo EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

if, I use this:

```
user@machine:~$ EDITOR=nano crontab -e (without sudo)
```

I get the following message:

```
no crontab for user - using an empty one
Error reading /home/user/.nano_history: permission denied
Press Enter to continue starting nano
```

Can anyone help my to troubleshoot this, thanks.

Comment: You should not be touching `sudo`, it is very easy to mess up permissions in your home directory, this is likely the cause of the error about `~/.nano_history`.

Comment: @o11c Thanks for the advice, let me check on that first.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/ is maybe a better place for this kind of questions.

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @o11c Thanks for your hint. You are right, there is something wrong with .nano_history file.

Answer (score 0):

is cron running?

```
$ps ax | grep cron
1236 ?        Ss     0:00 cron
```

if not check,

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cron.status
cron start/running, process 1236
```

if yours isnt running it'll say something like:
`cron stop/waiting`

try starting it with

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/cron start
```

--
hth

keith

EDIT:
My bad i see your cron is running after re-reading your post ... hmmm will look into this further as i remember having a similar problem a few months ago i also am running ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.
Sorry...