# PHP file not found in cronjob

Tags: php, cron

This is strange. On my Raspberry Pi (Debian) I can manually run a php file without a problem. However, I get this error when it is executed with a cron job:

`/bin/sh: 1: /var/www/html/sunrise-sunset.php: not found`

My cron job (using crontab -e) is as follows:

`* * * * * php /var/www/html/sunrise-sunset.php >> /var/www/html/logbook.log 2>&1`

However, when I add the shebang "#!/usr/bin/php" on the php page, the file is executed but all commented lines (`*/ xxx */`) are also read. Of course, this results in a lot of errors. When I remove those comments, it's a 'not found' error again.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: Two items: check the ownership and permissions of sunrise-sunset.php. Your user may be able to run them but the cron user may not be allowed.

Do you have any errors in the systems / cron log?

Comment: Oops, you're right, @CBroe. I was in the process of shutting down for the day and whipped out an answer without enough thought. I've deleted the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Meanwhile, I copied the code and pasted in a new empty php file. Weirdly enough, this fixed my issue while the permissions are still the same. Alright, well: problem solved!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)