# Crontab not executing Python script on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a Python script with the following code:

```
import subprocess
import sys

default = "Take a 20 second break - look at least 20 feet away!"
message = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else default

def sendmessage(message):
    subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', message])
    return

sendmessage(message)
```

called `takebreak.py`, which will send a system notification.

When I try to automate it using `crontab` like so:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/polo/git-repositories/takebreak/takebreak.py
```

It doesn't work. Running the command

```
/usr/bin/python /home/polo/git-repositories/takebreak/takebreak.py
```

in the terminal does work, which means it's not a file location problem, but rather something to do with `cron`. Any ideas?

**EDIT1:**

After debugging and looking at the logs, I can verify that cron is actually executing the commmand `export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/python /home/polo/git-repositories/takebreak/takebreak.py` every minute like I set it to do, but for some reason this command, while it should send a system notification, is not doing so.
Any ideas?

**EDIT2:**

The solution was to add some address bus thing (forget the exact code) that I found in another post, that ended up fixing it. Unfortunately, none of the answers or comments here helped with solving the problem, but thanks regardless!

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running

Comment: My crontab is running for sure, but for some reason the command in question will not work.

typing just `* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/notify-send blah` does not display anything

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron

Comment: Im having difficulty understand the solution in the code above. I'm supposed to add a DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS to my main code? And what would the address be?

Comment: To begin with, my suggestion would be to run `env|grep DBUS` and hardcode it in the crontab, just like `$PATH` in Will's answer. That will tell you if it solves the problem. If it does, there are a couple of suggestions on how to do it, in that answer I linked to. It would be easier if it were a bash script, you'll have to figure out the best way to do it, either from Python or by dumping the environment variable somewhere and using it from the crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that `notify-send` is not in your `$PATH` when running from `crontab`. First, figure out where it's stored:

```
$ which notify-send
/usr/bin/notify-send
```

For me, it's in `/usr/bin`.

At the top of your `crontab` file (`crontab -e`), set `$PATH`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

If you want to include whatever `$PATH` may have already been set before (safer), do this instead:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Make sure this includes the directory where your command is installed, if it's not installed in `/usr/bin`.

Of course, the other option, is to simply specify the full command path in your Python script:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/notify-send', message])
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to specify the absolute command path in the script? Setting the crontab PATH could have side-effects.

Comment: I'd say no--then the script is less portable as it depends on libnotify's tools being installed in the specified location. I added to my answer and put a safer way to modify `$PATH`, as well as changing the Python script to use the absolute path to the command.

Comment: Both methods didn't work, `cat /var/log/syslog | grep crontab` returns (among edits and such) the following line: `Mar 30 19:31:01 polo cron[634]: (polo) RELOAD (crontabs/polo)
`

Comment: Let's try writing our standard error output to a file and looking at it. Add `>/tmp/cron-error.log 2>&1` to the end of your crontab line, then look at `/tmp/cron-error.log` and see what it says.

Comment: I tried this before yet no log appeared after waiting several minutes (the crontab is set to run every minute right now)

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't very familiar with `notify-send`, but I think it needs a `$DISPLAY`. What about changing the command called by `cron` to: `sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /home/polo/git-repositories/takebreak/takebreak.py'`

Comment: Yeah in a comment on the original question I indicated that I was using DISPLAY, I tried adding your code so the final product is `* * * * * sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /home/polo/git-repositories/takebreak/takebreak.py'`

Comment: This is stumping me as well, haha. Let's rule out Python-related problems just for sanity. Let's try `* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/notify-send "weird test message"'`