# Cron job does not trigger on 30th of the month

Tags: cron, mongoexport

I have a cron job on an ubuntu server and I want to get it triggered everyday at time: 00.00

However, I have realized that job does not run on 30th of the month.
I checked the syslog and found:

```
Oct  1 00:00:01 mp-cronjob-01 CRON[10226]: (root) CMD (cd /root/MongoCollectionsCSV && sh /root/MongoCollectionsCSV/export_listing_salability.sh)
```

What I am doing wrong?

By the way, this is what I have added to crontab (script is for exporting all the documents from mongodb using mongoexport internal tool):

```
00 00 * * * sh the_script_name.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various reasons behind why your cron job is not running you can find troubleshooting steps for finding reason please find below answers which are having some good explanations...

[CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check all the alternative solutions.