# cron jobs error no such file or directory

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I setup a Cron job on my web hosting which runs my code every minute. but I still got an error that I cannot run the script. I do not know whether my command is wrong. here I have attached the coding and the error I got.

below is my PHP code.

```
$select_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_user)){
    $normal_w = $row['normal_wallet'];
    $interest_w = $row['interest_wallet'];
    $normal_w = $row['normal_wallet'];

    $run_interest = ($normal_w + $interest_w)*0.02;

    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET interest_wallet=interest_wallet-'$run_interest' WHERE status='active'");

}   ?>
```

The command I use:

[image: my command]

The error I get from the email:

[image: error]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions

Comment: check the given path you have given for cron setting once..

Comment: why i need to stop choosing mysql_* ? how can i select my db ?

Comment: apokryfos is saying to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` , `mysql` is removed from latest version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `php -q` to run php file

so it would be your command

```
php -q /home/ppfpapaf/public_html/cron_jobs/cron_jobs.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope Something wrong with your command. Thats the reason your cron cannot find a file directory.

Try something Like this in your Command Field:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/ppfpapaf/public_html/cron_jobs.php
```

Or

```
/usr/bin/php /home/ppfpapaf/public_html/cron_jobs.php
```