# Crontab doesn't execute R script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, cron

I'm trying to setup a Cron job on my system by adding the following line

```
17 12 * * * Rscript ~/path/to/file/script.R > ~/output_`date +\%d\%m\%y`.txt 2>&1
```

yet, I cannot see the file the output is being written to. I've consulted the following answers, but to no avail:

[Why did  my crontab not trigger](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/why-did-my-crontab-not-trigger)

[CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

When I run the following command on the terminal:

```
Rscript ~/path/to/file/script.R > ~/output_`date +\%d\%m\%y`.txt 2>&1
```

I get the output file as expected. I also added the following line to crontab:

```
* * * * * echo hi > ~/output.txt 2>&1
```

and it works just fine. I'm not sure what is wrong with the first command. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what if you use the full path instead of using `~`? In general, crontab does not understand those because its environment is very limited.

Comment: I've tried using the full path as well. That doesn't seem to be the issue. I ran the same thing on another ubuntu machine and it worked without any hassles.

Comment: Do you have any traces in the cron log?

Comment: I only have the begin, replace and end edit logs in the cron log

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by replacing `Rscript` in my crontab with `/usr/local/bin/Rscript` (or wherever your Rscript is located - do `which Rscript` to find out).

Answer (score 1):

Try Below trick, Create one script script.sh like below -

```
cat script.sh
Rscript ~/path/to/file/script.R > ~/output_$(date +\%d\%m\%y).txt 2>&1
```

And then create below entry in crontab.

```
17 12 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: why is this better? You are just replacing backticks with `$()`.

Comment: @fedorqui - Replacing backticks is just code improvement and the trick is to move the code into a separate script and execute it by cron(which is the Ideal syntax for cron job)

Comment: Then it is important to highlight this aspect of your answer. Also, I don't think it is going to work as is, you need to either put the shebang or indicate the binary in the cronjob

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR tried running the script according to your trick, but couldn't make it work. Executing `script.sh` on the terminal works fine, `35 19 * * * bash script.sh` does not ( I tried running it at 7.35 PM local time)

Comment: please mention the absolute path in cron job, like this - 

`35 19 * * * bash /home/user/script.sh`

Comment: @fedorqui - Your Suggestion has been considered, I will add them to Answer if trick solves this Question. Thank you!

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR still no luck. Same issue.

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar - Please make one more change like this `35 19 * * *  /home/user/script.sh` and Is there any error message, please paste here.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR sorry for the delay. Still no progress. I did not get an error message.

Comment: in fact it should be `35 19 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh`