# Cronjob is running but not executing python script

Tags: linux, cron

This is being marked as a duplicate but its not. I tried everything in this link
[CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Cron is running, scripts executes manually, permissions have been set, path has been checked. There are no errors or mail or messages or anything

Im at wits end, I have set a cronjob to run this python script every 5 minutes. I have it set up and according to cron status it is running, but the script is not executing. The script checks a ftp site for a file, if there is a new one it downloads it and there should be a new file everyday to download.

I just checked the crontab and its been running the process every 5 minutes for the last three days, but it has failed to execute the script, meaning the file doesn't get downloaded.

Now when i run the script manually it works and I get the file downloaded. The script has a shebang in it and when ran manually i can either run like this:(these all run the script just fine!)

```
   ./price_downloader
   /root/downloader/price_downloader
   python3 /root/downloader/price_downloader
```

i have tried a few different ways of writing it in crontab but it never executes.
I ran `chmod +x` on the file and still nothing
here is my crontab command:

```
*/5 * * * * /root/downloader/price_downloader
```

Ive also tried it with python 3 in the command:

```
*/5 * * * * python3 /root/downloader/price_downloader
```

I dont get whats going on. If I run the commands manually the script runs just fine why isn't it working with cron?

Comment: You need to examine system logs and your email. Probably there is an error message somewhere. See also [the Stack Overflow `cron` tag info page](/tags/cron/info) for troubleshooting tips and background.

Comment: like i said the script works manually there are no errors