# Cron is not Running for my laravel 5 project

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, cron

This question may be duplicate ([CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)) however, it does not resolve my issue. Let me explain this. By seeing the post in https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-task-scheduling-with-cron-job-example , I wanted to set the cronjob via terminal. I see from FTP that artisan has set in the path: `/var/www/html/projectName/`
and I believe that this server is Ubuntu. I ran this below command but did not happen anything.

```
* * * * * /var/www/html /var/www/html/projectName/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

From the above mentioned stackoverflow post, I ran the command `ps ax | grep cron` which return me:

```
1013 ?        Ss     0:57 /usr/sbin/cron -f
19067 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

I believe the path of cronjob is set as wrong. But how can I rectify this, I can't understand. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `/var/www/html/projectName/` needs to be set to the root directory of your application.

Comment: As like this ? `* * * * * /var/www/html/projectName/ /var/www/html/projectName/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: One solution that worked for me was adding the path to php before the artisan-path This is what mine was: 
/usr/bin/php

Answer (score 0):

I run this command and it works well

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/projectName/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

From: http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-5-task-scheduling-with-cron-job-example