# crontab shutdown command never runs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, linux-mint

Well as far as I can tell, I'm doing everything I've been told.

The command "shutdown -P now" at the commandline does exactly what I want - immediately shut down the computer. But using that command as a cron job just never happens.

I just want it to shut down Monday through to Friday, at 8:30pm, and then again at 9:30pm and 10:30pm.  So here's what I do;

I type "crontab -e", and I add this at the bottom of the file:

```
30 20,21,22 * * 1-5 shutdown -P now
```

I press CTRL+O to "save" it, and then CTRL+X to quit. I get the "crontab: installing new crontab" message at the prompt.

But come 8:30pm, no shutdown.  Nor at 9:30p, or 10:30pm.

---

Edit: Working through the list provided here;
[CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

I'm stopped at "Test cron is working".  I enter the command

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/file
```

And I get the error

```
Apps: command not found
```

Searching for this error in Google doesn't turn up anything relevant.

Also, I was finally able to see (thanks to the link) where to get my message log output - I'm in Linux Mint (should have mentioned that), so I needed the Ubuntu way of finding the log output.  The shutdown command appears to be run, and the only "error" message is "no MTA installed", which (from what I just read) is just for emailing the output.  Otherwise there doesn't seem to be any obvious error message... can someone make any sense of this?

```
domarius@Domarius-LinuxMint ~ $ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Aug  3 08:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[3259]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 09:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[3876]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 10:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[4122]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 11:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[4349]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 12:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[4719]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 13:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[5028]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 14:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[5317]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 15:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[5933]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 16:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[7083]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 20:26:38 Domarius-LinuxMint cron[1089]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Aug  3 20:26:38 Domarius-LinuxMint cron[1089]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Aug  3 20:30:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[2670]: (root) CMD (shutdown -P now "Shutting down...")
Aug  3 20:30:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[2671]: (domarius) CMD (/sbin/shutdown -p now)
Aug  3 20:30:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[2669]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  3 20:30:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[2668]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  3 21:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[3058]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  3 21:30:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[3232]: (domarius) CMD (/sbin/shutdown -p now)
Aug  3 21:30:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[3233]: (root) CMD (shutdown -P now "Shutting down...")
Aug  3 21:30:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[3231]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  3 21:30:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[3230]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug  3 22:17:01 Domarius-LinuxMint CRON[3515]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: try including the path (`/sbin/shutdown`)

Comment: Try executing from shell with the same user. Can you? Check logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744360/6115238

Comment: @marekful Yes I mentioned that at the start of my post.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Thanks - actually that's what I have in my last run, still nothing!

Comment: @NanoPish I've updated the original post with more info from what I learned at the link you gave; I've hit another dead end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After my question was unhelpfully downvoted with a link to a lot of things that didn't work, I got the help I needed on the Linux Mint forums - the secret was to edit crontab using the sudo command; "sudo crontab -e"  That and other useful info is at this post. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=275029&p=1507982#p1507982

Answer (score 1):

sudo vim /etc/crontab

## daily 10:00PM shutdown desktop

00 22 * * * root  /sbin/poweroff

Answer (score 1):

04/13/2021 update:

Running: Ubuntu 20

Steps I used to make cronjob turn the computer off M-F at 3:45PM

1. `$ sudo crontab -e`
2. `45 13  *   *  1-5 sudo shutdown -h now`

Answer (score 0):

Check your cron logs, usually in `/var/log/cron`.  Most likely it will be a path issue, use this.

```
30 20,21,22 * * 1-5 /sbin/shutdown -P now
```

Comment: Actually I currently am using /sbin/shutdown in my latest test since the post, still nothing.  And a wierd thing; I have /var/log, but no "cron" file or folder exists within it, even if I view hidden files.  I've posted some extra info in the comments on my original post.

Comment: _(domarius) CMD (/sbin/shutdown -p now)_ 
You are doing  shutdown as domarius. Is this user allowed to shutdown? If not combine with `sudo` . 
Ex: `/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -p now` and make sure it works on the command line first

Comment: thanks for your help, but as stated, the command works on the command line just fine.  But all's well - after my question was unhelpfully downvoted with a link to a lot of things that didn't work, I got the help I needed on the Linux Mint forums - the secret was to edit crontab using the sudo command; "sudo crontab -e"  That and other useful info is at this post. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=275029&p=1507982#p1507982

Comment: just wanted to give you credit for the correct answer, seems in my previous comment I didn't fully understand your solution, although specifying the paths isn't necessary.