# Script behaves differently when run from cron job and from command line using django manage.py when using a cron supervisor

Tags: python, django, cron

I know crons run in a different environment than command lines, but I'm using absolute paths everywhere and I don't understand why my script behaves differently. I believe it is somehow related to my cron_supervisor which runs the django "manage.py" within a sub process.

Cron:

```
0 * * * * /home/p1/.virtualenvs/prod/bin/python /home/p1/p1/manage.py cron_supervisor --command="/home/p1/.virtualenvs/prod/bin/python /home/p1/p1/manage.py envoyer_argent"
```

This will call the cron_supervisor, and it's call the script, but the script won't be executed as it would if I would run:

```
/home/p1/.virtualenvs/prod/bin/python /home/p1/p1/manage.py envoyer_argent
```

Is there something particular to be done for the script to be called properly when running it through another script?

Here is the supervisor, which basically is for error handling and making sure we get warned if something goes wrong within the cron scripts themselves.

````
import logging
import os
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from command_utils import email_admin_error, isomorphic_logging
from utils.send_slack_message import send_slack_message

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = CURRENT_DIR + '/../../../'

logging.basicConfig(
  level=logging.INFO,
  filename=PROJECT_DIR + 'cron-supervisor.log',
  format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)


class Command(BaseCommand):
  help = "Control a subprocess"

  def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument(
      '--command',
      dest='command',
      help="Command to execute",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
      '--mute_on_success',
      dest='mute_on_success',
      action='store_true',
      help="Don't post any massage on success",
    )

  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    try:
      isomorphic_logging(logging, "Starting cron supervisor with command \"" + options['command'] + "\"")
      if options['command']:
        self.command = options['command']
      else:
        error_message = "Empty required parameter --command"
        # log error
        isomorphic_logging(logging, error_message, "error")
        # send slack message
        send_slack_message("Cron Supervisor Error: " + error_message)
        # send email to admin
        email_admin_error("Cron Supervisor Error", error_message)
        raise ValueError(error_message)

      if options['mute_on_success']:
        self.mute_on_success = True
      else:
        self.mute_on_success = False

      # running process
      process = Popen([self.command], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
      output, error = process.communicate()

      if output:
        isomorphic_logging(logging, "Output from cron:" + output)

      # check for any subprocess error
      if process.returncode != 0:
        error_message = 'Command \"{command}\" - Error \nReturn code: {code}\n```{error}```'.format(
          code=process.returncode,
          error=error,
          command=self.command,
        )
        self.handle_error(error_message)

      else:
        message = "Command \"{command}\" ended without error".format(command=self.command)
        isomorphic_logging(logging, message)
        # post message on slack if process isn't muted_on_success
        if not self.mute_on_success:
          send_slack_message(message)
    except Exception as e:
      error_message = 'Command \"{command}\" - Error \n```{error}```'.format(
        error=e,
        command=self.command,
      )
      self.handle_error(error_message)

  def handle_error(self, error_message):
    # log the error in local file
    isomorphic_logging(logging, error_message)
    # post message in slack
    send_slack_message(error_message)
    # email admin
    email_admin_error("Cron Supervisor Error", error_message)
````

Example of script not executed properly when being called by the cron, through the cron_supervisor:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import logging
import os

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from utils.lock import handle_lock

logging.basicConfig(
  level=logging.INFO,
  filename=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'crons.log'),
  format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)
class Command(BaseCommand):
  help = "Envoi de l'argent en attente"

  @handle_lock
  def handle(self, *args, **options):

    logging.info("some logs that won't be log (not called)")

logging.info("Those logs will be correcly logged")
```

Additionally, I have another issue with the logging which I don't quite understand either, I specify to store logs within `cron-supervisor.log` but they don't get stored there, I couldn't figure out why. *(but that's not related to my main issue, just doesn't help with debug)*

Comment: Depending on how `.virtualenvs/prod/bin/python` was created, it might just be a symlink to the system Python.  You need to do more to actually *activate* the `virtualenv`. In addition, there are a number of other factors which differ between `cron` and interactive use; see [the Stack Overflow `cron` tag info page](/tags/cron/info) and perhaps also this FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running

Comment: Also, you seem to be reinventing `subprocess.call()`. You should probably be looking at `subprocess.run()` if you have a decently up-to-date Python.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python and in particular my answer there.

Comment: I already use `process = subprocess.Popen(bash_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` to run the actual script. I took a look at your links but couldn't find anything related to my issue. The `.virtualenvs` folder was created using virtualenv_wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cron` job can't just run the Python interpreter in the virtualenv; this is completely insufficient. You need to `activate` the env just like in an interactive environment.

```
0 * * * * . /home/p1/.virtualenvs/prod/bin/activate; python /home/p1/p1/manage.py cron_supervisor --command="python /home/p1/p1/manage.py envoyer_argent"
```

This is already complex enough that you might want to create a separate wrapper script containing these commands.

Without proper diagnostics of how your current script doesn't work, it's entirely possible that this fix alone is insufficient. Cron jobs do not only (or particularly) need absoute paths; the main differences compared to interactive shells is that cron jobs run with a different and more spare environment, where e.g. the shell's `PATH`, various library paths, environment variables etc can be different or missing altogether; and of course, no interactive facilities are available.

The system variables will hopefully be taken care of by your virtualenv; if it's correctly done, activating it will set up all the variables (`PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, etc) your script needs. There could still be things like locale settings which are set up by your shell only when you log in interactively; but again, without details, let's just hope this isn't an issue for you.

The reason some people recommend absolute paths is that this will work regardless of your working directory. But a correctly written script should work fine in any directory; if it matters, the cron job will start in the owner's home directory. If you wanted to point to a relative path from there, this will work fine inside a cron job just as it does outside.

As an aside, you probably should not use `subprocess.Popen()` if one of the higher-level wrappers from the `subprocess` module do what you want. Unless compatibility with legacy Python versions is important, you should probably use `subprocess.run()` ... though running Python as a subprocess of Python is also often a useless oomplication. See also my answer to [this related question.](/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation, helpful. I tried to `activate` but got `permission denied`, so I used `workon production;` which does the same thing, but it didn't fix it. I do believe that the issue isn't with the environment itself, because the cron does call the file I'm expecting, it just does nothing with it. I guess it somehow doesn't understand that it's dealing with a `Command` class instance and doesn't instantiate it. But it's very hard to troubleshoot indeed. What would you recommend instead to supervise proper cron execution and be warned when things go wrong?

Comment: I just added an additional example with minimal setup of a script called through the cron_supervisor which basically doesn't log whatever happens within its `handle` method

Comment: I just went through you long and detailed other answer. I use Python 2.7, which si why I also use `subprocess.Popen()`, since `subprocess.run()` isn't available in 2.7, if I understood correctly. I also read your advice about running python from python and if I understand correctly, I should rather call my cron_supervisor.py which wouldn't start a sub process but rather call other python modules to do what needs to be done. That actually makes sense... The reason why we did it that way is that those scripts were croned at first, then the supervisor got created on top. I'll give it a try!

Comment: You can basically only call `logging.basicConfig` once per process so that might be a reason to stick to a subprocess; or maybe switch to more detailed logging control. `subprocess.check_call()` should definitely be available in Python 2.7; your current code basically duplicates that, except you incorrectly pass a single string *as a list* to `Popen`. With `shell=True` the first argument should properly just be a single string.

Comment: I don't understand why `manage.py` calls `manage.py` or how that is supposed to make the separate module `envoyer_argent` available to it (that's the example module you ehow, right?). On the whole, having the manager manage itself seems like either a hugely overcomplicated design, or a simple mistake.

Comment: For debugging, I'd disable the logging to files and just collect the script's standard error into a file.

Comment: Yeah, the design is definitely wrong here, you're right about that. We converted a normal cron to a managed cron without thinking it further, our goal was to catch silent exceptions and it didn't occur to us that we should just do it differently and avoid all this overcomplication. Thanks for your input! (and yes, that's indeed `envoyer_argent` module, simplified)