# How to run a python script with cron on LINUX

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to run a python script on my raspberrypi using `cron`.

I did the following:

```
crontab -e # To edit a crontab job
```

After the cron file opened, I added the following line:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/path/to/file/example.py > /home/pi/cronlogs/mylog.log # JOB_ID_!
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, this cron job should be executed every time after the system booted up. However in my case, when I reboot the computer, the script will not be executed.

What's strange:

- I checked the log file and it's empty, so it seems like everything goes fine
- If I run the given command manually (so basically write the following code to the terminal) it executes and works correctly: `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/path/to/file/example.py > /home/pi/cronlogs/mylog.log`

I guess I missed something really obvious but I can't see it. Please can I ask for any advise how to debug this. Thanks!

Comment: why do you need to point the example.py file at the log file? Also, whats the end goal?

Comment: try something like `@reboot echo "hello" > /home/pi/cronlogs/mylog.log` and check syslog if this doesn't work(or `journal -xe` for systemd)! Consider as whom this crontab is being executed and if this user has the correct permissions.

Comment: Consider a [mcve], it it relevant that the executed program is Python?

Comment: @MartinGergov your example will add 'Hello' to mylog.log

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Based on comment above I guess it is. Also script I'm trying to execute is some kind of scrapper which run until it get killed so this may be important as well.

Comment: @Andurit make sure you do `sys.stdout.flush()` after prints or whatever you are using to log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Answer (score 0):

The cron definition looks correct; I just checked this on my Pi running Debian stretch and it works OK:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/example.py > /home/pi/mylog.log
```

Some other possible reasons it might not work:

- working directory issue (if you're using relative paths)
- a long running script (being a scraping script it might take a while to complete) - you can check if it's still running using `ps aux | grep python`
- the script does not output anything (would need some more details about the script)

Just to be sure you catch any errors from the script, redirect *stderr* to *stdout* by using `2>&1`

Comment: Hello, so the issue would be on script? It actually should run for ever and it has output normally in a console. However for more info this is the script: https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py

Comment: It's possible; edit the cron definition to include stderr as well in your log file:  
`@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/path/to/file/example.py > /home/pi/cronlogs/mylog.log 2>&1`