# Run Python script from Ubuntu cronjob

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to run a simple python script on a VM running Ubuntu 18 hosted on my Synology. The python script simply prints date and time in a file so I can check if it ran or not. It looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
with open('file.txt','a') as file:
    file.write('Recorded at: %s\n' % datetime.now())
```

I made a cronjob that looks like this:

```
* * * * * /home/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 /home/Documents/crontest.py
```

I have tried many variations. For instance not writing 3.7 and just simply write 'python'. I tried the default python path /usr/bin/python3.7.

Furthermore I tried to ad the shebang #!/home/anaconda/bin/python3.7 to the script and leaving out the path in the cronjob.

It feels like I am missing something elementary here. I tried many options as posted on Stack and other forums, but none of the options seem to fix my problem.

Comment: 1) The indetion of your Python code is broken. 2) It is `#!`, not `!#`. 3) Where is Python *really* installed? What does `which python3` tell you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Comment: Could also try commands: _py_, _py3_, _python3_ etc.

Comment: @LutzHorn 1,2) My bad, poor copying skills. fixed it in the question. 3) /home/anaconda3/bin/python3. I changed the code in the cronjob accordingly, but it don't make a difference.

Comment: It may be permission issue what happens if you run it manually? or if you change cron to ```/home/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 /home/Documents/crontest.py 2>&1 | tee crontest.log```

Comment: Ok, I fixed it thanks to @LutzHorn (I used the wrong path) combined with a solution in the  potential duplicate where I found that you can not use relative path within python scripts when running cronjobs.

Comment: Running manually worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using relative links in python scripts is not allowed when running cronjobs. So it works when I write it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
with open('/home/Documents/file.txt','a') as file:
    file.write('Recorded at: %s\n' % datetime.now())
```

Furthermore, I used the wrong path to python. I wrote /python3.6 instead of /python3 which I found through typing

```
which python3
```

in terminal.