# Cronjob is not executing on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I need to hit an api every 15 minutes, so added below line. but it does not executing on server. If API hit it will update the table with some values, but nothing is happening.
Any help appreciated.

```
MAILTO=suresh.k@example.com
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
*/15 * * * *    root    curl -x GET http://example.com/api/index/cronjob
```

Comment: Where/how did you add those line? Via `crontab -e`?

Comment: sudo nano /etc/crontab

Comment: Usually the http method for update should be POST, not GET. And if you execute the command from command line do you get the expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Answer (score 0):

1) This format work for me:

```
*/15 * * * *    /usr/bin/curl --silent -X GET http://example.com/api/index/cronjob
```

try it. (**!** **X** in uppercase **!**)

2) check method - POST or GET are needed to update table?

3) if you open address http://example.com/api/index/cronjob in browser, will the table be updated?