# -bash: */10: No such file or directory when running cron job

Tags: bash, cron

In my current directory, I have a bash script called `run_job.sh`. This script runs perfectly fine.

I'm trying to schedule this script to run every 10 minutes using a cronjob. Here is the code that I am using:

```
*/10 * * * * run_job.sh
```

Now, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
-bash: */10: No such file or directory when running
```

I'm new to cron jobs so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a valid Bash script. You probably want to provide it as input to `crontab` instead.

Comment: @tripleee can you please elaborate on this? This is my first time using a cron job

Comment: You're not revealing how you are trying to run this, but the error message looks like you did something like `bash file`. This attempts to run `file` as a Bash script, which it is not. Try `crontab <file` instead.

Comment: Or maybe you just typed that at the bash prompt; run `crontab -e` and type it into your editor instead. (If you end up in a hostile `vi`, type `i` to insert something, and esc `:` `w` `q` to save it and quit.)

Comment: So, my bash script runs a few python scripts. Looking at some resources online, I noticed they run the command I included to schedule a job. Are you suggesting I include it within `crontab -e` then run `crontab run_job.sh` in the terminal?

Comment: No, the use of `crontab` is to update your `cron` settings. It's really unclear which part of this you are having trouble with but developing new wild ideas down here in the comments seems like a step in the wrong direction. Maybe look for a simple "hello world" cron tutorial and come back when you have done that successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message in your question suggests that you passed the `crontab` snippet to Bash somehow. That's not how you schedule a job; you type the command `crontab -e` at the Bash prompt and edit your Cron schedule in your favorite editor. *That's* where you would type in this snippet. When you save the file and exit the editor, `cron` will take your new schedule into use.

However, you should be aware that your normal `PATH` and other features of your interactive environment will not be available to `cron` jobs. At a minimum, you will probably need to specify the path to your script. If it's in `$HOME/bin/run_job.sh`, that's what you need to put in the final field in the `crontab` entry. (There may be more tweaks you have to do which can't be inferred from the information you have provided; see e.g. [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) for further tips.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is the scheduling line from crontab (see man crontab). Further, I recommend against the /10 format, as it is not accepted by cron on all operating systems. To be safe, it is better to be explicit, as in:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * run_job.sh
```

Comment: I've rarely if ever had a requirement for a crontab to be portable to systems that don't support the `/10` syntax.

Comment: Some of us manage multiple different operating systems, including Solaris. It's still a valid reason.

Comment: But it's not at all an answer to the question at the top of this page. Once you earn enough reputation points, you will be able to leave comments; until then, probably focus on askrng and answering questions.