# automatic backup in postgresql creates the empty backup

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cron

I want to automate backup of PostgreSQL database using crontab in UNIX. I have tried but it will create 0 bytes backup.

My crontab entry is:

```
24 * * * *  /home/desktop/myscript.sh
```

and my sh file contains the following code:

```sh
pg_dump -U PostgreSQL -d test > b.backup
```

It will create the file but the file is empty. Is there any solution? Is there any way to solve this question?

Comment: Check your system log file for error messages from `cron`. Probably your `cron` job needs a password or some other way to authenticate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running

Comment: The proposed duplicate contains a large number of troubleshooting steps which you don't seem to have performed. Please [edit] your question to show what debugging you have done (or probably simply delete it when you manage to solve the probdem on your own while troubleshooting).

Comment: do you have any social media or whatsapp contact number so that i can direclty asked to you

Comment: The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a knowledge base so you can solve your problem yourself based on existing answers. Again, all I can do in private is spoon-feed you the troubleshooting steps one by one.

Answer (score 3):

Don't assume that any environment variables are set in a cron job; be explicit:

```sh
/full/path/to/pg_dump -U postgres -d test > /full/path/to/b.backup
```

Look for mail in your inbox for failure reports from `cron`.

Comment: i didn't understand what are you saying ?

Comment: I am talking about fixing your shell script so that it works.

Comment: Should I write sudo before pg_dump

Comment: Did I say anything about `sudo`?

Comment: What is the full path of pg_dump? It should be anything? /home/desktop pg_dump......

Comment: No offense meant, but I cannot help you, since I don't know your machine and you don't seem to have basic knowledge about computers. You will need to find someone who does, can sit down with you and lead you through the first steps.

Comment: If it's in `/usr/bin/pg_dump` it will probably work without any amendments to the `PATH`. If it's somewehere less standard like `/opt/local/postgres/pg_dump` you will need to use the explicit full path, or update your script to amend the `PATH` variable so it's visible. At the prompt, `type pg_dump` will print the full path to the binary.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify full path to pg_dump

```
#!/bin/bash
BKPDATE=$(date +%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S)
cd /var/lib/pgsql/12/backups
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dump -Fc dl_db > DBNAME_$BKPDATE.dmp --verbose 2> LOG_$BKPDATE.log
```

or you must add PostgreSQL's bin directory to the path like below:

```
vi /var/lib/pgsql/.pgsql_profile

   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-12/bin
```

Comment: I AM USING POSTGRES 9.2 VERSION THIS SYNTAX WORKS IN THIS VERSION

Comment: if you will specify 9.2 bin directory instead of 12 it must work