# Crontab not executing script and log file not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I am struggling to create a cron job since morning. Here is the process I did.

#### The task I am trying to run `management.sh`,

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/mysite.com/myproject/
source ../venv/bin/activate
python manage.py dbbackup
deactivate
```

1. I made this script executable by doing `sudo chmod +x /var/www/mysite.com/myproject/management.sh`.
2. Then with `crontab -e` I added the following line to run every 2 mins.

   `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /var/www/mysite.com/myproject/management.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1`

---

#### Problem

`sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON`, this is what I see,

```
Jul 26 09:52:01 test-svr-loc1 CRON[23583]: (dexter) CMD (/usr/bin/sh /var/www/mysite.com/myproject/management.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1)
Jul 26 09:52:01 test-svr-loc1 CRON[23582]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

When I check the `cron.log`, it is empty.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at `/var/log/cron.log`. Your cron tries to tell you that your job is generating errors and cron tries to send it by e-mail, which fails because no MTA ([Mail Transfer Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)) is set up.

Comment: Without access to the error message we really can't tell. The "no MTA" part tells you it tried to send you email with an actual error message, but wasn't able to. Try to pare this down into still simpler components. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running

Comment: Is your job allowed to write in `/var/log/cron.log`?

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks. I gave permissions to the log folder and now it is logging. I will create a new question about the issue now. It says cron `can't cd to` folders inside the bash script it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Crontab is executing script. As per [@Cyrus's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098645/crontab-not-executing-script-and-log-file-not-working/63098989#comment111579300_63098645) in the comments, it was a permission issue. Cron was not able to write to my log as I created it with `sudo`. Changed permission back to me and it is now logging.