# Autorun gulp at the start up in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, cron, gulp, autostart

I try to start [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start) by running `/home/m/gulp` at the start up Kubuntu 20.04 LTS  (from Ubuntu).

It was not possible to run gulp with just one line Console/Terminal:

`/home/m/gulp`

`bash: ./gulp: No such file or directory`

That's probably normal.

so i tried successful:

```
cd /home/m
gulp
```

Therefore i stored this inside `/home/m/gulp.sh` SH-Script.

It works as expected if I start it manually by typing `/home/m/gulp.sh` into the terminal.

I got no results  after reboots by these tries:

1. System Settings > Autostart > Add Script: `/home/m/gulp.sh`
2. sudo crontab -e

   ```
   crontab -e
   @reboot `/home/m/gulp.sh`
   ```

I changed the SH-Script, added **sudo** , and it works now also  automatically after reboot:

```
cd /home/m
sudo gulp
```

That works for me. BTW It not ask me for Password ([configure sudo](https://askubuntu.com/a/147265/1017209)). But I find it a bit strange that I sometimes need a sudo in the sh script and sometimes not. If I start it via crontab it needs a sudo, if I start it myself (manually) I don't need a sudo.

Comment: BTW if i try `./gulp` i get `No such file or directory` . `gulp` works

Comment: Root's `crontab` uses a different syntax. Is the script executable? Why doesn't running `gulp` with an absolute path work? That sounds like a bug in its own right.

Comment: Your last comment doesn't make sense; can you rephrase please?

Comment: I _think_ the Autostart option only starts something when you log in to your desktop, not when the system boots. I haven't used Ubuntu in many years so this could be a red herring, though.

Comment: @tripleee if i writ `crontab -l` into terminal is see my script is correct added to the list.

Comment: works if i use as sh-script at startup: `cd /home/m sudo gulp`. sudo not needed if i start it manually

Comment: Your enumeration shows `sudo` but then inside you don't use `sudo`. Is this in `root`'s `crontab` (by way of `sudo`) or in your own? Does `gulp` need to be run as root? And again, is your script executable? Have you checked the system log for results from `cron`?

Comment: Yes, I think there might be something wrong with the system. Today I had to correct an error with sudo of mine like this: https://askubuntu.com/a/471503/1017209 I tried to check whether crontab was working correctly (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274737/how-do- i-know-if-crontab-is-working-fine). But I cannot interpret the result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ37V.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running has a large number of troubleshooting steps. You really need to go through those.

Comment: The `grep` output just shows that `syslog` is configured to log `cron` output. The actual log files are usually in `/var/log/syslog` or similar. And please don't post images of text.

Comment: end of `/var/log/syslog` : `06:31 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
07:01 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
` Maybe `Starting Hostname Service` is interesting. hmm

Comment: the cron [step 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) test is not working `m@kubuntu:~$ * * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> ./temp.txt `
`2020-09-26 02-01-28.mkv: command not found`
`m@kubuntu:~$ ls -al ./temp.txt`
`-rw-rw-r-- 1 m m 455 Sep 27 12:34 ./temp.txt` .

Comment: That looks like you typed that on the command line rather than ran it from `cron`. The command `*` tries to run all the files in your current directory (or, well, the first one with the others as arguments) and the result looks like `./temp.txt` already existed before you ran that command.

Comment: `hostname` is a service which tells you what your host name is, and has no meaning here. You want to look for `cron` errors.