# Why ttylog from crontab is null?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a quick question for you :)
I've created a bash script which is doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
ttylog -f -b 38400 -d /dev/ttyAMA0 -t 25 > /home/pi/Desktop/test/output_file.txt
```

It works perfectly well, I get data in the file output_file.txt
However, if I launch this script from a crontab, I get an empty output_file.txt

Do you have an idea why there is a difference between the crontab and launching the script directly?

Thanks!

François

Comment: Is `ttylog` in the cron job's `PATH` (which is *not* the same as your interactive shell's `PATH`)? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)