# CRON not running python script - Debian/RPi

Tags: python, linux, debian, raspberry-pi4

I have a python script (priceChange.py) which I'm trying to run using CRON from the path below.

`35 10 * * 1-5 /home/pi/Desktop/priceChange.py`

when I check `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` it shows this:

`Mar 23 10:35:01 AlexM CRON[16200]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/priceChange.py)` with no error.

When I run the script manually it works, the end result being an email being sent to myself.

Clearly something is missing in the crontab line, but I'm lost. Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Does your script have a proper shebang line?

Comment: Please review the troubleshooting checklist [Cron job not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) and probably [edit] to clarify your situation if that doesn't solve it for you.

Comment: @rdas what's a shebang line?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way how run your script causes the problem. add `python` command ahead.

`35 10 * * 1-5 python /home/pi/Desktop/priceChange.py`