# rename script to adjust certain patterns within a filename in debian

Tags: regex, linux, bash, rename

I'm currently a bit stuck, trying to adjust filenames within a folder tree if they have one or both of the following:

1. Remove 'S00' - 'S99' -that part is to be cut out of the filename.
   `s/[sS](0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/` could do that I think
2. Any free standing double digits get an 'E' in front of them. Find `/\b([0-9]{2})\b/` and substitute `E$1` somehow

Example:
any of these

- [lorem ipsum] dolor sit amet 07 [consetetur][1080p].mkv
- [lorem ipsum] dolor sit amet S04 07 [consetetur][1080p].mkv
- [lorem ipsum] dolor sit amet S04 E07 [consetetur][1080p].mkv

are changed to

- [lorem ipsum] dolor sit amet E07 [consetetur][1080p].mkv

within their respective subfolders.

Ultimate goal is to automate the process of renaming files as they appear (that latter bit I have to figure out once I'm done with this) so the kodi scraper can recognize episodes

This is how far I got, as you can see, its still a mess as I've found this rename script here a while ago, but I don't know how to properly apply the regex, I just slapped it in

```
#!/bin/bash

start_dir="//srv/MEDIA2/"
find "$start_dir" -name '*.*' -type f \
  |sort \
  |while read name; do 
     ((i++))
     mv -i "$name" \
#remove season part
       "$(printf 's/[sS](0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/' "$(dirname "$name")" $((i)) "$(basename "$name")")"
#prepend E to free standing double digits
       "$(printf 's/\b([0-9]{2})\b/' "$(dirname "$name")" $((i)) "$(basename "$name")")"
    
done
```

Currently it returns

```
//home/user/./rnscript.sh: line 14: s/[sS](0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/: No such file or directory
//home/user/./rnscript.sh: line 16: s([0-9]{2}/: No such file or directory
```

If anyone with knowhow in that area could help me out to get this running, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of incremental variable `$i`?

Comment: I initially thought it was meant to keep it running after renaming until it has checked all files this way. but now I realise it is a leftover from another script, which was designed to add a number count to the name. Aah carp ok this is even more of a mess than I thought it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

start_dir="//srv/MEDIA2/"                       # double // may be meaningless
for name in "$start_dir"/**/*.*; do             # search the directory recursively
    [[ -f $name ]] || continue                  # skip if "$name" is not a file
    newname=$(sed -E 's/[sS](0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]) +//; s/\b([0-9]{2})\b/E\1/' <<< "$name")
    if [[ "$name" != "$newname" ]]; then        # skip if the filenames are the same
         echo mv -- "$name" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

Drop `echo` if the output looks good.
We do not have to sort the files as the variable `$i` is not used.

**[EDIT]**

If you want to change `S04E02` to `E02` as well, please replace the `newname=` line above to:

```
newname=$(sed -E 's/[sS](0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]) *//; s/\b([0-9]{2})\b/E\1/' <<< "$name")
```

The difference is just change `+` to `*`, meaning zero or more whitespaces.

Comment: oooh it does work!!! thank you so much!
it returns this for each skipped file but i don't mind that. 
```mv: '//srv/MEDIA2/dateien2//youtube-icon.png' and '//srv/MEDIA2/dateien2//youtube-icon.png' are the same file```

Comment: ok one problem, it seems to be unable to see subfolders with spaces in their name is that possible?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you elaborate on the pathnames which cause the problem? I'll fix the "same file" issue in one go.

Comment: Checked again, I think it only checks the linked folder itself, but no subfolders.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I've updated my script to search the files in the subdirectories recursively. The "same file" issue is also fixed. If your `bash` does not support the `shopt` built-in command, please let me know.

Comment: So like:
//srv/MEDIA2/Anime/Title Name/

//srv/MEDIA2/Anime/Title Name 2/

//srv/MEDIA2/Anime/Title Name 3/

Comment: trying to run that script in a 20 minute interval via crontab, any idea why that doesn't work by any chance? This is how it looks

```*/20 * * * * /usr/bin/sh //home/pi/rnscript.sh```

Comment: Common pitfalls in cron-job are 1) file permission 2) path issue (you need to specify absolute paths, not relative paths). You will also find useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running). In addition please examine the log files. If my script may causing the problem, let me know.

Comment: thanks! or might put this up as a service, whichever works, playing around with it right now.
also, there is a variation i missed "S04E02", basically season and episode without a space in between, is there a way to include this?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code which will support `S04E02` type of expression.