# Raspberry Pi 4B, running Python Script using serial at boot

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm currently using crontab on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B to launch my python script at boot.
I've added this at the bottom of `sudo crontab -e` :

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/start.sh > /home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1 &
```

My `start.sh` script is like that :

```
#!/bin/sh
# start.sh

cd /home/pi/Desktop/Python_Scripts/Projet
sudo python3 main.py
```

If I run the shell script manually, everything works fine, but **when it runs at boot**, the **serial communication doesn't work**.

I already tried to add some delay in my python script to wait for the serial interface to be fully initialized but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help

**EDIT :** I must clarify that the script runs perfectly if I run

```
sh /home/pi/start.sh > /home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1 &
```

in the command line. However, the only thing that doesn't work if I run it at boot with crontab is the serial communication (looking up signals with an oscilloscope, it doesn't send data through the serial interface) but every other aspect of the program runs fine.

Comment: If this is in `root`'s crontab, you don' need `sudo`; you are already `root`. It's even possible that this is causing the error.

Comment: `#!bin/sh` is wrong; it is looking for a directory `bin` in the current directory, and then for `sh` within that. You want `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Please review [Cron job not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) for standard troubleshooting tips.

Comment: @tripleee I've tried both with and without sudo and neither of them worked...
I forgot the `/` before bin when posting the questions, but it was in the script, thanks I edited the question
Thank you, I'll look it up

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `cron` is executing before the serial interface is initialized and causing your python script to raise an exception.

This can be verified by adding a relatively small delay (ie: 30 seconds) into your python script to see if it then functions properly.

If the script only needs to be run once, a simple fix could be to utilize the `autostart` file instead of `cron`. Commands in this file are run only after the gui is brought up successfully. This is located at `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

Comment: My script doesn't raise any exception and, as I already said in my post, I already tried adding a delay before writing data on the serial interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open terminal
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`
3. Add this line to the file:

```
@path/app_name
```

4. Save and exit

Answer (score -1):

I also use Raspberry pi4.
I reccomend you use `crontab -e` without `sudo`. 
My `crontab -e` like this: 
`@reboot bash /usr/bin/start_counter.sh`
My  `/usr/bin/start_counter.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while true
do
    python3 /home/pi/people_counter_android/main.py
done
```

**In my way its work. I hope this help you.**

Comment: If the script needs access to privileged resources, it does need to run as `root` somehow. Of course, we can't tell from the information in the question whether that is actually the case; but the talk about "serial" gave me the impression that it needs to control the unit's I/O ports.

Comment: the script starts well with crontab, but doesn't communicate through the serial interface. Unfortunately, your suggestion does not fix my problem