# Python script executed @reboot with crontab

Tags: python, python-requests, cron, telegram-bot

Good morning everyone,

I'm doing a Telegram Bot using Telegram API (I'm just using requests(http://api.telegram.org/sendMessage.....) and it's working fine when I manually execute my script with `python myscript.py`).

I want to let the script run all the time so I went to the crontab of my raspberry and add `@reboot python /home/pi/myscript.py`. Then I did `sudo reboot` and no message on telegram... I have no idea why it is not working, do you have the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you could find some hints here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron may not know where to find the Python interpreter because it doesn't share your user account's environment variables.

There are 3 solutions to this:

1. If Python is at `/usr/bin/python`, you can change the cron job to use an absolute path: `@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py`
2. Alternatively you can also add a PATH value to the crontab with `PATH=/usr/bin`.
3. Another solution would be to specify an interpreter in the script file, make it executable, and call the script itself in your crontab:

   a. Put shebang at the top of your python file: `#!/usr/bin/python`.

   b. Set it to executable: `$ chmod +x /home/pi/myscript.py`

   c. Put it in crontab: `@reboot /home/pi/myscript.py`

Adjust the path to the Python interpreter if it's different on your system.

[Reference](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=162994)