# Crontab that calls python script via docker-compose not executing

Tags: python, docker-compose, cron

I have a crontab set up to run a python script called from a docker-compose command:

```
* * * * * cd path/to/repo && docker-compose run worker python -c "from directory.module import test_function; test_function()"
```

The module & test_function looks like this:

```
import logger

def test_function():
    logger.info('Hello')
```

The docker container is up and running. However, when I go to check my log file, nothing has been written to it. I'm not sure what I need to do to get this working correctly.

Comment: Can you verify that the job actually runs? Do you get any errors in your email? Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running for troubleshooting instructions and [edit] to update accordingly.

Comment: There is a message in `/var/mail/username`. It says `/bin/sh: docker-compose: command not found`

Comment: So there, you probably have to fix your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I created a shell script (`test_cronjob.sh`) to run the commands I need.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/bin/
docker-compose -f /full/path/to/docker-compose.yml run worker python -c "from directory.module import test_function; test_function()"
```

And edited my `crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /full/path/to/test_cronjob.sh
```

Or just simply editing the `crontab -e` without the shell script, like below:

```
* * * * * PATH=/usr/local/bin/ docker-compose -f /full/path/to/docker-compose.yml run worker python -c "from directory.module import test_function; test_function()"
```

Comment: If you supply the ful path to `docker-compose`, overriding the `PATH` with a bogus value seems wrong, and will probably wreck any other `cron` jobs of yours. Just to be explicit, you should *add* this directory to the default `PATH`, not lose the previous values (`/bin:/usr/bin` etc are quite crucial for normal system operation).