# Ubuntu - run bash script on startup with visible terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, startup

I am wanting to run a bash script on startup in Ubuntu 20.04 with the **terminal visible**. The test.sh file is located at /usr/bin/test.sh. I can get the test.sh file to run at startup but not in a visible terminal window.

Contents of test.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "hello";
```

I can not get it to work, I have tried (individually):

**Crontab (with and without the '&' and with/without "sudo")**

```
@reboot bash test.sh &

@reboot /usr/bin/test.sh &

@reboot DISPLAY=:0 xterm -hold -e bash -c "bash test.sh" &

@reboot DISPLAY=:0 xterm -hold -e bash -c "bash /usr/bin/test.sh" &
```

**Startup Applications Command**

```
sudo bash /usr/bin/test.sh
bash /usr/bin/test.sh
/usr/bin/test.sh
```

**Creating a Service at /etc/systemd/system/testService.service**

```
[Unit]
Description = Test Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory= /usr/bin
ExecStart= /usr/bin/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And start, enable and checked status..

```
systemctl start testService.service
systemctl enable testService.service
systemctl status testService.service
```

But failed to start.

Any help / pointing in a better direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To get a GUI terminal window to appear when you run your script:

Add to "Startup Applications" (under command):

```
bash test.sh
```

Contents of test.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
    DISPLAY=:0.0 xterm -hold -e bash helloWorld.sh
```

Contents of helloWorld.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "hello";
```

For me, this opened an XTerm terminal window upon login and ran the helloWorld.sh script.

Comment: This answer worked well, instead I gave `path/to/bash.sh` as command and it still worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a Unix, the X server gets started at the end of the startup. And starting X clients makes only sense, when someone has logged in. So your aim "start X client when computer starts" makes no sense, because there is no X server running when you try to start the X client.

You can start X clients after login. If you use a classical installation, use [`.xinitrc`](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Xinitrc) for this. If you use a different desktop environment, use whatever this desktop environment provides you.

- [Gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-apps-auto-start.html.en)
- [KDE](https://help.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/desktopguide/C/desktop-tips.html)
- [XFCE](https://superuser.com/questions/1302604/launch-an-application-at-startup)

Comment: I use Gnome, the 'tweaks tool' simply adds a 'Startup Application', which I have already done as noted in my question but it does not run.

Comment: You should [report a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME), if Gnome does not work as expected.

Comment: Many, many Unix installations do not start up X11 automatically at any time. It is a common arrangement for modern desktop systems (and even then, an optional feature which you can turn off, or choose to not install in the first place), but by no means a feature of Unix itself.