# cron: Running PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, cron, debian, bitnami

I am trying to run PowerShell script from `cron` (Debian/Ubuntu based Bitnami distro).

At the moment I'm trying to run it using a **.sh** script, which calls the **.ps1** script and logs an execution time like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
echo $dt executing >> run.log
/usr/bin/pwsh -File "/home/bitnami/tale_2.ps1"
```

When I run this script directly from console, everything works. However, when I try to run it from cron (user and root) using:

```
* * * * * cd /home/bitnami && /home/bitnami/run.sh
```

I've tried also to run it directly:

```
* * * * * pwsh -File "/home/bitnami/tale_2.ps1"
```

even with `pwsh` with absolute path with no luck at all to run the `ps1` script file. However, when I run the `.sh` file directly from console, it executes the `ps1` file. `run.log` gets updated either through cron, also running directly.

This is the script, I'm trying to excecute with `cron`.

```
#!/opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh -Command


# [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()

$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
$port.PortName = “/dev/ttyr00”
$port.BaudRate = “9600”
$port.Parity = “None”
$port.DataBits = 8
$port.StopBits = 1
$port.ReadTimeout = 5000 # 5 seconds
$port.DtrEnable = “true”
$port.open() #opens serial connection
$port.IsOpen


$dataSQL = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$count = 500
for($i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++){
$dataSQL += ""
}

$comNO = 0

function convertToHex($bytes, $offset, $count)
{
    $result = '';
    for ($i = $offset; $i -lt ($offset + $count); $i++) {
        $result += ' ' + $bytes[$i].toString("X2");
    }
    return $result;
}

function convertToInt($bytes, $offset, $count)
{
    $result = @()
    for ($i = $offset; $i -lt ($offset + $count-4); $i+=2) {
        $pom_result = ($bytes[$i+1]*256 + $bytes[$i])  ;
        If ($pom_result -gt 32767 ) {$pom_result -= 65535 }
        $result += $pom_result  ;
    }
    return $result;
}





$s=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$s.Add("AA 55 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 08")
$s.Add("AA 55 00 00 01 00 1C 00 00 00 1C")
$s.Add("AA 55 00 00 01 00 30 00 00 00 30")
$s.Add("AA 55 00 00 01 00 44 00 00 00 44")
$s.Add("AA 55 00 00 01 00 58 00 00 00 58")
$s.Add("AA 55 00 00 01 00 6C 00 00 00 6C")
$s.Add("AA 55 00 00 01 00 34 01 00 00 35")






$s.ForEach({
    Start-Sleep -m 1000 # wait 100ms seconds until device is ready
    write-host $args[0].ToString()




        try
        {

        # [Byte[]] $request = 0xAA,0x55,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x44,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x44
        # [Byte[]] $request = 170,85,0,0,1,0,68,0,0,0,68

        [byte[]] $request = $args[0] -split ' ' | foreach-object { invoke-expression "0x$_" }
        write-host -noNewline 'send : ';
        write-host $request; #  Display parameters


        $port.Write($request, 0, $request.Count)
        Start-Sleep -m 500

            #  receive
            $recvBuffer = new-object byte[] 128;
            $recvLen    = $port.read($recvBuffer, 0, 128)-1;

            #  display
            write-host -noNewLine 'recvLen: ';
            write-host $recvLen;

             # write-host -noNewLine 'recvBuffer: ';
             # write-host $recvBuffer;
             # write-host ' ';

            #write-host -noNewLine 'receive: ';
            #convertToHex $recvBuffer 0 $recvLen | write-host;

            #write-host -noNewLine 'receive Int: ';
            #convertToInt $recvBuffer 2 $recvLen | write-host;
            $data_int = convertToInt $recvBuffer 2 $recvLen
            write-host -noNewLine 'data_int: ';
            write-host $data_int;


            $smernik = $data_int[2]
            write-host -noNewLine 'smernik: ';
            write-host $smernik;

            #$dataSQL.Add($data_int[3]);
            #$dataSQL[$smernik] = ($data_int[3]);
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
                $dataSQL[$smernik + $i] = ($data_int[$i+3]);
                $comNO++;
            }


            write-host ' ';


        # while($myinput = $port.ReadExisting())
        # {
        # $myinput

        # }
        }


        catch [TimeoutException]
        {
        # Error handling code here
        }

        finally
        {
        # Any cleanup code goes here
        }


    })
write-host -noNewLine 'dataSQL: ';
write-host $dataSQL



#pause
$port.Close() #closes serial connection
$port.IsOpen;

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1



#./tale-sql.sh "INSERT INTO public.datale(an_01, an_02, an_03, an_04) VALUES ($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4)"
#./tale-sql.sh "INSERT INTO public.datale(an_01, an_02, an_03, an_04) VALUES ($dataSQL)"
#./tale-insert_sql.sh "$dataSQL"


$var_an01 = $dataSQL[8]
$var_an02 = $dataSQL[9]
$var_an03 = $dataSQL[10]
$var_an04 = $dataSQL[11]
$var_an05 = $dataSQL[12]
$var_an06 = $dataSQL[13]
$var_an07 = $dataSQL[14]
$var_an08 = $dataSQL[15]
$var_an09 = $dataSQL[16]
$var_an10 = $dataSQL[17]
$var_an11 = $dataSQL[28]
$var_an12 = $dataSQL[29]
$var_an13 = $dataSQL[30]
$var_an14 = $dataSQL[31]
$var_an15 = $dataSQL[32]
$var_an16 = $dataSQL[33]

/home/bitnami/tale-sql.sh "INSERT INTO public.datale(an_01, an_02, an_03, an_04, an_05, an_06, an_07, an_08, an_09, an_10, an_11, an_12, an_13, an_14, an_15, an_16) VALUES ($var_an01,$var_an02,$var_an03,$var_an04,$var_an05,$var_an06,$var_an07,$var_an08,$var_an09,$var_an10,$var_an11,$var_an12,$var_an13,$var_an14,$var_an15,$var_an16)"
```

Comment: What does "no luck at all" mean? Does `run.log` get updated? What does the PowerShell script do, does it write any logs or have any side effects you can observe? If so, what _did_ you observe?

Comment: Yes, run log get updated from running directly from console and also from cron. However, ps1 script is executed only from console run, not from cron. Sorry, I didn't stated that. PowerShell script writes data to a database, which is done running through console (.sh) but not from cron.

Comment: Please review [Cron job not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) for general `cron` troubleshooting tips, then [edit] your question with more diagnostics. As it stands, this doesn't have enough details to conclude anything. Does the `pwsh` script contain commands which need a particular `PATH`?

Comment: Tangentially, the `cd` appears useless.

Comment: @tripleee : ```cron``` is running, i know that because I got entry logged in ```run.log``` file. PowerShell script does not need a particular path, therefore I agree, that cd is useless. When i run ```.sh``` file from console, the ```.ps1``` script gets executed. When from ```cron```, then not. It only writes to ```run.log``` file. Thanks for the edit btw.

Comment: I'll try again: please show us the contents of the script, perhaps reduced to a [mre]. The question I linked to contains a number of tips for troubleshooting `cron` jobs generally; it's not about "cron not running" really.

Comment: Right, I've edited my question to include the .ps1 script I'm trying to run from cron.

Comment: And what do you see in the system logs from `cron`? Do you receive email with an error message?