# Cronjob does not work for the local asdf elixir path

Tags: cron, elixir, macos-ventura, asdf

My crontab file looks like:

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/dmitriy/.asdf/shims/elixir ~/work/scripts/my_script.exs
```

And that script doesn't work. As I understand it, cron cannot detect the location of elixir. I run it on macOs Ventura.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See the bottom of my answer for a solution.

Comment: I don't agree that this isn't related to programming, but it definitely needs more debugging details. See [Cron job not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) for some troubleshooting steps; at the very least, it should show you what information to include in a question about a problem you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on `macOS 12.5.1`, and I have elixir installed with asdf as well.  My path to elixir is the same as yours but with my user name instead:

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/elixir
```

I used a full path to my elixir script:

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/elixir /Users/7stud/elixir_programs/my_prog.ex
```

my_prog.ex contains:

```
IO.puts "Cron job just finished"
```

I redirected the output of stdout and stderr from the elixir script to a log file (>> is append):

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/elixir /Users/7stud/elixir_programs/my_prog.ex >> /Users/7stud/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

Here is what I see in `cron_output.log`:

```
/Users/7stud/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.16.0-otp-26/bin/elixir: line 247: exec: erl: not found
/Users/7stud/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.16.0-otp-26/bin/elixir: line 247: exec: erl: not found
/Users/7stud/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.16.0-otp-26/bin/elixir: line 247: exec: erl: not found
/Users/7stud/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.16.0-otp-26/bin/elixir: line 247: exec: erl: not found
/Users/7stud/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.16.0-otp-26/bin/elixir: line 247: exec: erl: not found
/Users/7stud/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.16.0-otp-26/bin/elixir: line 247: exec: erl: not found

...
...
```

It looks like erl, i.e. the erlang command, can't be found.

I also have python installed with asdf, and it has the same path as elixir but with python instead of the word elixir.  Here's a cron job for python:

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/python /Users/7stud/python_programs/1.py >> /Users/7stud/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

Here's my python program `1.py`:

```
print("Cron job just finished")
```

Output in cron_output.log:

```
Cron job just finished
Cron job just finished
Cron job just finished
Cron job just finished
...
...
```

The interplay between elixir and erlang seems to be the problem with scheduling elixir scripts.

This worked for me:

```
*/1 * * * * PATH=~/.asdf/shims:$PATH; /Users/7stud/elixir_programs/my_prog.ex >> /Users/7stud/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

The last part:

```
>> /Users/7stud/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

just redirects stdout and stderr to a log file.  You don't have to do that.  I get system mail if there are errors when executing the cronjob or if there is unhandled output:

```
Last login: Mon Feb 26 08:57:10 on ttys009
You have new mail.

~%  mail
Mail version 8.1 6/6/93.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/7stud": 8 messages 8 new
>N  1 7stud@7studs-MacBook  Mon Feb 26 09:13  18/749   "Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash "
 N  2 7stud@7studs-MacBook  Mon Feb 26 09:14  18/749   "Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash "
 N  3 7stud@7studs-MacBook  Mon Feb 26 09:15  18/749   "Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash "
 N  4 7stud@7studs-MacBook  Mon Feb 26 09:16  18/749   "Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash "
 N  5 7stud@7studs-MacBook  Mon Feb 26 09:16  18/749   "Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash "
 N  6 7stud@7studs-MacBook  Mon Feb 26 09:18  18/745   "Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash "
 N  7 7stud@7studs-MacBook  Mon Feb 26 09:19  18/745   "Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash "
 N  8 7stud@7studs-MacBook  Mon Feb 26 09:19  18/745   "Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash "
? 1
Message 1:
From 7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro.local  Mon Feb 26 09:13:01 2024
X-Original-To: 7stud
Delivered-To: 7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro.local
From: 7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro.local (Cron Daemon)
To: 7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro.local
Subject: Cron <7stud@7studs-MacBook-Pro> /bin/bash -lc "elixir /Users/7stud/elixir_programs/my_prog.ex"
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=7stud>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=7stud>
Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2024 09:13:00 -0700 (MST)

/bin/bash: elixir: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your shell from the crontab, which will pick up the desired environment.

For bash:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -lc "elixir ~/work/scripts/my_script.exs"
```