# python3 working on terminal but not on cron job

Tags: python, cron, netsuite, pyodbc

My python code is working fine but I am  not able to run by using cron.

The cron setup I have tried:

`*/2 * * * * python3 /var/folder1/filename.py >>> /var/folder1/cronlog/cron.log 2>&1`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folder1/fileNAme.py", line 23, in <module>
    netsuite_connection = pyodbc.connect(netsuite_connection_string, autocommit=True)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Comment: Obviously your python is running, if that error message is from that cron job, as this is a python error message. The problem seems to be, that your SQL connection in that python script is not working in the cron job. Can the lib `'/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so'` be accessed? There seems to be a driver issue with the user running the cron job.

Comment: The triple redirection is a shell syntax error. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Going forward, see also [Cron job not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Comment: Very often there is a problem with something missing or set differently in the environment. I would check that among first things.